# Property of bisectors of right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ $\angle C=90^\circ$, $AA'$ and $BB'$ are angle bisectors intersecting at $I$ ($A'\in BC$, $B'\in AC$). What would be the easiest way to prove that projection of $I$ onto $AB$ lies in equal distances from projections of $A'$ and $B'$ onto $AB$?

The reason I’m asking about the easiest way rather than about any solution is that I think it’s quite clear all the lengths can be calculated either in terms of sides of triangle or trigonometrically via its angles. Both ways seem to be too ugly. So I’m hoping there is smart geometrical solution.

Comment: At the moment you haven't identified the points $A'$ and $B'$ - are they supposed to be the points where the angle bisectors meet the sides $BC$ and $CA$ of the triangle respectively?

Comment: Yes, now it’s clarified.

Comment: When you ask for "the easiest way", does that mean that you already know one or more ways to solve the problem? If so, you should tell us all the ways you know, so we don't waste our time duplicating your effort. If you don't know a way to do the problem, do you really insist on the easiest way, or will any old way make you happy?

Comment: Okay, please see the explanation I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the incircle (with center $I$ and radius $r$) of $\triangle ABC$, and let it meet $BC$ at $P$. Since $IP \perp BC$, we have $IP \parallel AC$. (*Note: This is why the right angle at $C$ matters.*) Also, $|IP|=r$.

Let $Q$ be the point "near" $A^\prime$ on the incircle such that $IQ \parallel AB$; then, $\angle PIQ = \angle A$ and $\angle A^\prime I Q = \angle A^\prime IP = \frac{1}{2}\angle A$. By SAS, $\triangle IPA^\prime \cong \triangle IQA^\prime$, whence $A^\prime Q \perp IQ$, which is to say: the radius $IQ$ is the projection of $IA^\prime$ onto a line parallel to $AB$. This projection is congruent to the projection of $IA^\prime$ onto $AB$ itself.

The same argument applies to the corresponding projection of $IB^\prime$, so that the projections of $A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ onto $AB$ each lie at distance $r$ from the projection of $I$.

Comment: That’s a nice solution. Thanks!